# Find the interval of convergence of a power series with a single endpoint

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, power-series

The given series is:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(x^{2n+1}+2x^{2n+2}\right)$$
I know that the interval of convergence can be found by the ratio test, so what I tried was:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^{2n+3}+2x^{2n+4}}{x^{2n+1}+2x^{2n+2}}=x^2$$
Now we know that $-1<|x^2|<1$ or just $x<1$.

Then solving for the single endpoint:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(1^{2n+1}+2^{2n+2}\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}1^{2n+1}+2^{2n+2}=\infty$$
So the endpoint diverges, and the interval is $(-\infty,1)$

Comment: $|x|<1$ implies $-1<x<1$. You had your inequalities wrong.

Comment: The interval of convergence has to be centered in $0$, I can't see how could it be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series does not converge for $x \leq -1$. A series $\sum a_n$ cannot converge unless $a_n \to 0$. Can you check that in this case the general term does not tend to $0$ if $ x \leq -1$? The correct interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Why does the inequality change from $x^2$ to $x$?

Comment: @ChetBarkley I am not using ratio test at all. Ratio test for the entire series is  is not too convenient here. Note that convergnce for $|x|<1$ can be derived by just writing the given series as  sum of two geometric series.